# TaffyDB and document modification capabilities

Tags: javascript, database, offline

Does TaffyDb modify the Json object in the javascript document or is it on,ly a temporary modification?
Could i use it to store and modify data permanently?( i have a web server i just want to make a offline web app containing tsome of the info im gonna parse to the db later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TaffyDB does not store data by default. You can use the .store() method to store data in the browsers local storage. Otherwise you'll need to roll your own cookie based storage or connect to a backend server to store your changes.